# can we retrieve a column present in one stored procedure into another stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, procedure

I'm using a single table and I have generated ProfileID (Which is a primary key for the table) in one procedure and now i want to use that same id in another procedure for inserting rest of the table fields. How to call that generated profileID . Query may not be clear but any kind of help is indeed welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `last_insert_id()`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Just take a look at the examples shown there.